# Getting error while rerun of failed scenarios in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber

I was trying to rerun the failed scenarios in cucumber, for this I had designed two runner files, one is the actual runner file which has path of feature files along with rerun plugin which specifies path of rerun.txt file and the other runner file which has path of rerun file as feature to be run, So after running both the runner files for the failed scenarios I am getting this error :-

```
WARNING: No features found at file:/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/Reports/rerun.txt
```

Please help me to resolve this error and automatically run the failed scenarios of rerun.txt file.

The actual runner class file is as below:-

```
package com.framework.runners;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/com/framework/features",glue = {"com/framework/utils" ,"com/framework/stepDef"},
        tags = "@run",
        plugin = {
                "pretty","json:target/Reports/JsonReport/report.json","junit:target/Reports/Junitreports/report.xml","html:target/Reports/HTMLReport",
                "rerun:target/Reports/rerun.txt"
        },monochrome=true)

@Test
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

The rerunner class file is as below:-

```
package com.framework.runners;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(features = "target/Reports/rerun.txt",glue = {"com/framework/utils" ,"com/framework/stepDef"},
        plugin = {
                "pretty","json:target/FailedReports/JsonReport/report.json","junit:target/FailedReports/Junitreports/report.xml",
                "html:target/FailedReports/HTMLReport"},
        monochrome=true)

@Test
public class ReRunTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

The pom.xml configuration is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.CucumberHybrid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.16.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>Cucumber Framework Execution Report</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/Reports/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/Reports/JsonReport/report.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <buildNumber>42</buildNumber>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testngtest</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <systemPropertyVariables> <IsGridSetup>${is.grid}</IsGridSetup>
                        <HubUrl>${hub.url}</HubUrl> <FeatureName>${feature.name}</FeatureName> <TagName>${tag.name}</TagName>
                        <BrowserType>${browser.type}</BrowserType> </systemPropertyVariables> -->
                    <forkCount>3</forkCount> <!-- how many parallel vm get created and execute -->
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks><!-- Every it will create a new vm for
                        the execution and will not use any existing -->
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore><!-- The execution will continue
                        even if there is a test failure -->
                    <includes> <!-- Specify the file name -->
                        <include>**/*TestRunner.java</include><!-- This will include all the file
                            which has "Runner" as suffix in their name -->
                    </includes>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- <suiteXmlFile>${testngxml.location}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The console logs are as below:-

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< org.example:com.CucumberHybrid >-------------------
[INFO] Building com.CucumberHybrid 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ com.CucumberHybrid ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ com.CucumberHybrid ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ com.CucumberHybrid ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.CucumberHybrid ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ com.CucumberHybrid ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.framework.runners.TestRunner
[INFO] Running com.framework.runners.ReRunTestRunner
Aug 10, 2020 4:37:17 PM io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier get
WARNING: No features found at file:/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/Reports/rerun.txt
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.851 s - in com.framework.runners.ReRunTestRunner
@run
Scenario: To test search functionality with blank submit                           # src/test/java/com/framework/features/Home.feature:7
[INFO ] 2020-08-10 16:37:18.331 [main] BaseSetup - New Webdriver instance invoked
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 8150
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Aug 10, 2020 4:37:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[INFO ] 2020-08-10 16:37:20.357 [main] BaseSetup - Chrome browser instance launched successfully
  When user opens browser and navigates to test url                                # com.framework.stepDef.Common_stepDef.user_opens_browser_and_navigates_to_test_url()
The page title verified is My Store
[DEBUG] 2020-08-10 16:37:28.123 [main] HomePage_PF - Banner on homepage of website has been validated.
  Given user should be on home page                                                # com.framework.stepDef.Home_stepDef.user_should_be_on_home_page()
[DEBUG] 2020-08-10 16:37:28.159 [main] HomePage_PF - Search field on homepage has been validated.
  And search textfield should be visible                                           # com.framework.stepDef.Home_stepDef.search_textfield_should_be_visible()
[DEBUG] 2020-08-10 16:37:30.526 [main] HomePage_PF - Search icon has been clicked.
  When user clicks on search button                                                # com.framework.stepDef.Home_stepDef.user_clicks_on_search_button()
      java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:96)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:776)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:44)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
    at com.framework.stepDef.Home_stepDef.user_clicks_on_search_button(Home_stepDef.java:32)
    at ���.user clicks on search button(file:///Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/src/test/java/com/framework/features/Home.feature:10)
  Then user should be displayed validation message "Please enter a search keyword" # com.framework.stepDef.ProductList_stepDef.user_should_be_displayed_validation_message(java.lang.String)
    Scenario To test search functionality with blank submit has been failed
    Embedding To test search functionality with blank submit [image/png 365303 bytes]
[INFO ] 2020-08-10 16:37:31.638 [main] HomePage_PF - Webdriver instance has been closed
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.975 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.framework.runners.TestRunner
[ERROR] com.framework.runners.TestRunner.runScenario["To test search functionality with blank submit", "Optional[To test the Search feature of application]"](1)  Time elapsed: 13.995 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   TestRunner.runScenario expected [true] but found [false]
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.
Please refer to /Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-cucumber-reporting:3.16.0:generate (execution) @ com.CucumberHybrid ---
[INFO] About to generate Cucumber report.
[INFO] File '/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/Reports/JsonReport/report.json' contain 1 features
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing annotation @ and hence no feature is found. Try this -

`features = "@target/Reports/rerun.txt"`

---

After discussion in comment section

Rename ReRunTestRunner to start with any letter after "T" (TestRunner, original feature file), as Cucumber picks up feature file in alphabetical order

Comment: I applied the change but its still not running instead its giving error like :- io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to parse 'target/Reports/rerun.txt'
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: target/Reports/rerun.txt

Comment: How are you running the project? i looked into your console log again and damn! ReRunTestRunner runs before TestRunner, how do we even expect it to have any feature?

Comment: I can run my project through maven and also by testing.xml file. Yeah you are right my resruntestrunner runs before TestRunner class how to prevent this ??

Comment: can you share your TestNG.xml file?

Comment: I am not using TestNG.xml to run my tests I am using runner file directly to run my test you can see my pom.xml

Comment: can you try renaming your ReRunTestRunner to start with any letter after "T" (TestRunner)? as Cucumber picks up feature file in alphabetical order.

Comment: I renamed my actual TestRunner to ProjectRunner and surprisingly it ran firstly it ran both the files first it ran the actual runner and after that it ran rerun txt file scenario even though its giving filenotfoundexception but then also at end it says 2 Test Run

Comment: my issue has been solved as earlier I was getting 1 test run at the end but now I am getting 2 Test run thanks for your support

Comment: glad to hear :)

Comment: I have updated the ans, can you accept it? The only reason i am asking is i am just a beginner here and don't even have reputation to add a comment :(

Comment: worked for me. Please make it is the right solution.